# Расчет размера ползунка для скроллера

Tags: алгоритм

Может у кого есть алгоритм расчета параметров для скроллера? Интересует

1. Расчет размера ползунка относительно ширины видимой области.
2. Расчет размера постраничной прокрутки (в пикселях).

Answer (score 2):

Это достаточно просто.

1. l = (b^2)/a
      где: l - размер ползунка, b - размер видимой области, a - размер всей панели.
2. Размер страницы равен размеру видимой области.

Все значения будут иметь одинаковую размерность.

Comment: Почему именно такая формула, с квадратом?

Answer (score 1):

Размер ползунка должен быть пропорционален размеру видимой области к размеру всей области:

```
L = VisibleWidth / AreaWidth * ScrollerWidth
```

чтобы не было проблем в краевых случаях, добавляем мин/макс ширину:

```
L = Max(Min(VisibleWidth / AreaWidth, 1) * ScrollerWidth, MinWidth)
```

Размер "страницы" при скроле кликом - равен размеру видимой области